# How to get CSS content animation working on iOS

Tags: css, ios, webkit, css-animations

My CSS content animation is not working on iOS, both Safari and Chrome.  But it works on Android and Windows desktop.

I saw other similar questions on SO and google.  The fix was to use `-webkit-*`, but there is no `-webkit` for content.

```
#animated-tagline::before {
    content: "some text";
    -webkit-animation: animate infinite 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {

    0% {
        content: "some other text";
    }
    50% {
        content: "some more other text";
    }
    100% {
        content: "even some more other text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is currently no iOS support for animating the content property: https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/